# How to install .xap phonegap build in windows phone 8?

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I have developed one simple game by using phonegap android BUT after build for windows, ios, android, blackberry etc, its working only for android devices, so I can install apk file for android devices BUT for windows .xap file is not detecting in the windows phone 8 device. I have downloaded .xap from after build in phonegap.
Anybody please advice me How to install .xap into wp8? 
Any steps and procedure appreciated a lot.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install xap:

1. you have to register as windows phone developer [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join)
2. Now connect the phone to computer with a data cable. Go to this location `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Phone SDK 8.0` and run Windows Phone Developer Registration shortcut. You need to provide your microsoft account details to unlock the phone for debugging.
3. Now run the Application Deployment shortcut from the same location and you'll be able to install the app to windows phone ( you can do this with visual studio also).

---

[according to phoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Platform%20Guide) also you need the windows phone sdk.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir.. I have unlocked phone and more over Im not developing native app for windows. I have build .xap file from phonegap and was trying to install that into my windows phone BUT after copying  into sd card also its not available to install

Comment: Kk ya but phonegap build xap is not detecting in win phone 8 wat to do for that??

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe this program detects every file with .xap extension. set the target as device connect the phone, you should be good to go.. if you're doing for windows phone 8

Comment: Hey im not developing app for windows natively, I dont have any windows sdk and all.. I have developed app in phonegap android and I build it for windows and android, builded .xap file from phonegap is not detecting in win phone

Comment: It won't detect if you do it via sd card or something like that. At a minimum you need XapDeploy.exe to deploy anything to windows phone, if it is not in store.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Platform%20Guide page also tell that you need it...

Comment: yes from xapDeploy.exe i have installed.. Thanks a lot

Comment: I found the XapDeployCmd.exe file better to use as you can put it in a script to install on your installed phone as below...

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe" /installlaunch .\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap /targetdevice:de

Answer (score 4):

After unlock your phone run

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe
[image: Deployer tool image]

select target device/emulator,
browse .xpa file ,
then Deploy

***Note:Your device screen should not be locked and uninstall if already installed app have same name.***

Answer (score 2):

What about sideloading .xap files from SD-Card ?

Try this link, it may be helpful.
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card?signin=true

Comment: Did that. You should be able to install your app if its located *anywhere* on your phone, by clicking 'install local app' in the window store app. Didnt work for me - option didnt appear - it looks like either the app or the phone or both need to registered and approved for something before that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlock and install the XAP installer within the Windows Phone SDK

Comment: Yes I have unlocked phone BUT once I paste .xap file into phone then it will not be available in sd card

Comment: You must install the SDK on your computer in order to install the .xap file. There is no other way to install it on your phone (except if you have a beta access to your windows phone store dev center)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also cmd line command like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe /installlaunch D:\PhoneApp1.xap /targetdevice:xd` or rely on automated tools like cordova, but you'll need Update 2 of Visual Studio 2012 to be able to access the `XapDeployCmd.exe`command. `XapDeploy` is already with the package of wp8 SDK, `XapDeployCmd`is not.

---

**Source:**

[1] [How to Deploy .xap using command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444498/how-to-deploy-xap-using-command-prompt)

[2] http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

[3] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx