# How to Deploy .xap using command prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-phone, xap

I want to deploy xap to windows phone emulator 7.1 using command prompt and i have been following the msdn article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_commandline)

i am able to build the project using this command:
`MSBuild D:\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1.csproj`

but when i run this command:    XapDeployCmd.exe /installlaunch D:\PhoneApp1.xap /targetdevice:xd i get error saying "'XapDeployCmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."
i have the visual studio update 2 installed.what does this mean and how should i use command prompt for deploying my xap.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if XapDeployCmd.exe direcoty is on your environment path?

if not you can add the whole path, like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe  /installlaunch D:\PhoneApp1.xap /targetdevice:xd

I would also check if you have any emulator installed