# How to deploy .xap files in Windows Phone

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I developed a sample hello world app in cordova, I want to install it in my mobile phone which is far away from me.

I copied the `.xap` file that is generated, but i can't able to install it.

I don't have 'install local apps' option in the store. I also tried in many way. The phone is with the person far away from me, and the person can't install windows sdk or visual studio.

How can i insall it in the target phone ?

Note : I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553263/how-to-install-xap-phonegap-build-in-windows-phone-8) question, but it needs `XapDeploy.exe`  which wants to install the sdk , which i don't want.

How can i do this, Pls help me

I tried many way

Comment: Is the phone developer unlocked?

Comment: Yes, it was phone developer unlocked

Answer (score 1):

The only way suitable for your scenario is using the private beta in the store, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt185377.aspx.

Comment: Is that suitable for Windows Phone 8.1 too ?